# Fabric.js apply filter to Image.fromURL

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a fabricjs canvas [v2.4] and i'm trying to add an image via url and then apply a filter (grayscale for example).

I've managed to add the image via url but i cant quite get the filter part right. I've followed some examples online but i always get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).filter is not a function
```

Here's a short snipper of the code that involves the adding + filter while you can see the full fiddle attached below as well. The two lines of code that does that filtering is uncommented for now to not cause the error.

```
var img_url = "https://www.fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/seongbukgu/mobile_browser_cam/v2/img/test.png"

// add image to fabriccanvas
function addImg_d() {

  fabric.Image.fromURL(img_url, function(img) {
    // uncomment the 2 lines below and you'll get an error
    //img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
    //img.applyFilters(d_canvas.renderAll.bind(d_canvas));
    img.scale(1);
    d_canvas.add(img);
  });
};
```

I've also tried different images / base64 data but i still get the exact same error. Any ideas ? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```js
// init fabric canvas
var d_canvas = new fabric.Canvas('d_canvas', {
  isDrawingMode: false,
  selection: false
});
d_canvas.enableGLFiltering = false;

// resize canvas on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas_d, false);

function resizeCanvas_d() {
  d_canvas.setDimensions({
    width: 300,
    height: 200
  });
}

// resize on init
resizeCanvas_d();

// click to add image
var captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    addImg_d()
  }, 100);
});


var img_url = "https://www.fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/seongbukgu/mobile_browser_cam/v2/img/test.png"

// add image to fabriccanvas
function addImg_d() {

  fabric.Image.fromURL(img_url, function(img) {
    // uncomment the 2 lines below and you'll get an error
    //img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
    //img.applyFilters(d_canvas.renderAll.bind(d_canvas));
    img.scale(1);
    d_canvas.add(img);
  });
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#capture {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="d_canvas" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>

<button id="capture">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `img.applyFilters()` no need to pass argument as you are setting filter.

***DEMO***

```js
// init fabric canvas
var d_canvas = new fabric.Canvas('d_canvas', {
  isDrawingMode: false,
  selection: false
});
d_canvas.enableGLFiltering = false;

// resize canvas on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas_d, false);

function resizeCanvas_d() {
  d_canvas.setDimensions({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  });
}

// resize on init
resizeCanvas_d();

// click to add image
var captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
captureButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    addImg_d()
  }, 100);
});


var img_url = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/files/Eye_Roll_Emoji_large.png?v=1541768914"

// add image to fabriccanvas
function addImg_d() {
  fabric.Image.fromURL(img_url, function(img) {
    // uncomment the 2 lines below and you'll get an error
    img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale());
    img.applyFilters();
    img.scale(1);
    d_canvas.add(img);
  },{crossOrigin:'anonymous'});
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#capture {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="d_canvas" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>

<button id="capture">Add</button>
```